# Create multiple stops directions google maps Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, google-maps

I made this part of the code to display the directions on a google map
But at the moment I only have start and endlocation
I would like to have more stops and make the route as good as possible
How can I enter multiple stops?
That's what I did until now

```
<table>
        <tr>
          <th>Start</th>
          <th><GmapAutocomplete @place_changed="setPlace" /></th>
          <th style="width: 50%;"><button class="btn" @click="addMarker(0)">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>End</th>
          <th><GmapAutocomplete @place_changed="setPlace" /></th>
          <th style="width: 50%;"><button class="btn" @click="addMarker(1)">Add</button></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Directions component

```
import { MapElementFactory } from "vue2-google-maps";
export default MapElementFactory({
  name: "directionsRenderer",
  ctr() {
    return window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  },
  events: [],
  mappedProps: {},
  props: {
    origin: { type: [Object, Array] },
    destination: { type: [Object, Array] },
    travelMode: { type: String },
  },
  afterCreate(directionsRenderer) {
    console.log(1)
    let directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.$watch(
      () => [this.origin, this.destination, this.travelMode],
      () => {
        let { origin, destination, travelMode } = this;
        if (!origin || !destination || !travelMode) return;
        directionsService.route(
          {
            origin,
            destination,
            travelMode,
          },
          (response, status) => {
            if (status !== "OK") return;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
            //debugger
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  },
});
```

```
<DirectionsRenderer
        travelMode="DRIVING"
        :origin="startLocation"
        :destination="endLocation"
      />
```

And my functions

```
setPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
    },
    addMarker(index) {
      const marker = {
        lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng(),
      };
      if (index === 0) this.startLocation = marker;
      if (index === 1) this.endLocation = marker;
      this.center = marker;
      console.log(this.startLocation, this.endLocation)
    },
```

So I have everything ok so far, everything is going super well but I would need to have more stops
From what you see I only have one variable for the end
How can I proceed?
Can I adapt to the current code?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before and this will help you:

first of all you need to add `waypoints` and `optimizeWaypoints` keys to `directionsService.route` in DirectionsRenderer.js file
after that you need to bind this keys to `DirectionsRenderer` component in your project, as well as you need to create an array called waypnt in your component file and push all `Destination` points and `stopover: true` key on it like this:

```
this.waypnt.push({
      location: { lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng },
      stopover: true,
    });
```

look at this:

DirectionsRenderer.js

```
    import { MapElementFactory } from "vue2-google-maps";

export default MapElementFactory({
  name: "directionsRenderer",

  ctr() {
    return window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  },

  events: [],

  mappedProps: {},

  props: {
    origin: { type: [Object, Array] },
    destination: { type: [Object, Array] },
    waypoints: {type: Array},
    travelMode: { type: String },
    optimizeWaypoints: {type: Boolean}
  },

  afterCreate(directionsRenderer) {
    let directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();

    this.$watch(
      () => [this.origin, this.destination, this.travelMode, this.waypoints, this.optimizeWaypoints],
      () => {
        let { origin, destination, travelMode, waypoints, optimizeWaypoints } = this;
        if (!origin || !destination || !travelMode || !waypoints) return;
        directionsService.route(
          {
            origin,
            destination,
            travelMode,
            waypoints,
            optimizeWaypoints,
          },
          (response, status) => {
            if (status !== "OK") return;
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  },
});
```

MapContainer.vue

```
    <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Map Project</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- Adding Company Location: start -->
        <div class="company-location">
          <b-form>
            <b-input-group class="mb-3">
              <GmapAutocomplete @place_changed="originPoint" />
              <b-input-group-append class="ms-2">
                <b-button class="btn-success" @click="addOriginPoint">
                  Add Location
                </b-button>
              </b-input-group-append>
            </b-input-group>
          </b-form>
        </div>
        <!-- Adding Company Location: end -->

        <!-- Map Container: start -->
        <GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="12" map-type-id="terrain" class="map">
          <GmapMarker
            :key="index"
            v-for="(m, index) in markers"
            :position="m.position"
            @click="center = m.position"
          />
          <DirectionsRenderer
            travelMode="DRIVING"
            :origin="startLocation"
            :destination="endLocation"
            :waypoints="waypnt"
            :optimizeWaypoints="true"
          />
        </GmapMap>
        <!-- Map Container: end -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Add passenger' Name & Loacation: start -->
        <b-form>
          <b-form-group
            label="passenger's Name"
            label-for="passengerName"
            class="my-3 text-start"
          >
            <b-form-input
              id="passengerName"
              type="text"
              placeholder="passenger's name"
              value=""
              required
            ></b-form-input>
          </b-form-group>
          <b-form-group
            label="passenger's Location"
            label-for="passengerLocation"
            class="my-3 text-start"
          >
            <GmapAutocomplete
              id="passengerLocation"
              @place_changed="setPlace"
            />
          </b-form-group>
          <b-button class="btn btn-success w-100" @click="addDestinationPoint">
            Get Direction
          </b-button>
        </b-form>
        <!-- Add passengers's Name & Loacation: end -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <!-- data table: start -->
        <div class="mt-4">
          <h3>Employees table</h3>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Employee name</th>
                <th>Trip duration</th>
                <th>Pickup point order</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <dataTable />
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- data table: end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DirectionsRenderer from "./DirectionsRenderer";

export default {
  name: "MapContainer",
  data() {
    return {
      center: { lat: 41.04538761823768, lng: 28.990736439754617 },
      currentPlace: null,
      originPlace: null,
      markers: [],
      destinationPlaces: [],
      originPlaceLocation: [],
      path: [],
      passengers: [],
      startLocation: null,
      endLocation: null,
      waypnt: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
    },
    originPoint(originPoint) {
      this.originPlace = originPoint;
    },
    addDestinationPoint() {
      const passengerName = document.getElementById("passengerName").value;
      if (this.currentPlace || this.destinationPlaces.length <= 7) {
        const marker = {
          lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng(),
        };
        const passengerInfo = {
          name: passengerName,
          pickUpPoint: marker,
        };
        this.markers.push({ position: marker });
        this.path.push({ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng });
        this.destinationPlaces.push(this.currentPlace);
        this.passengers.push({ passengerInfo });
        console.log(this.passengers);
        this.center = marker;
        this.currentPlace = null;
        this.endLocation = marker;
        this.waypnt.push({
          location: { lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng },
          stopover: true,
        });
      } else {
        alert("You are allowed to add 8 passenger only!");
      }
    },
    addOriginPoint() {
      if (this.originPlace && this.originPlaceLocation.length == 0) {
        const originMarker = {
          lat: this.originPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: this.originPlace.geometry.location.lng(),
        };
        this.markers.push({ position: originMarker });
        this.path.push({ lat: originMarker.lat, lng: originMarker.lng });
        this.originPlaceLocation.push({ position: originMarker });
        this.center = originMarker;
        this.startLocation = originMarker;
      } else {
        alert(
          "You have alrady added an origin place! if you want to change it please reload the window"
        );
      }
    },
  },
  components: {
    DirectionsRenderer,
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

for more info, look at this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints#maps_directions_waypoints-javascript